# Laravel unit testing a route with a query string

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

```
$response = $this->call('GET','abc?foo=bar');
```

I'm unable to get **PHPUnit** to transmit `foo` as a request variable.  Any thoughts?  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's rather not possible. It works without any problems. You haven't mentioned Laravel version of why do you think you don't have those data when reaching controller.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is not a **PHPUnit** issue, it is a **Laravel** one.

The `call()` method has the following signature:

```
call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null);
```

You should send the query string as an associative array.

If you want to directly test a controller, you should use the `action()` method, which has the following signature:

```
action($method, $action, $wildcards = [], $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

thx, @dov-benyomin-sohacheski. the call() method seemed to be limited in the manner in which it renders the url response.  i believe it's a php cli command and not transmitting over the wire.  even when using an associative array i could not get it to recognize query parameters.  post data was no problem, but i needed to emulate GET calls.

the solution for me proved to be using Guzzle as a http client.  they have a [query string parameters spec](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters).

i'm new to testing so learning a lot quickly...feel free to correct me if i missed something.